# Inconsistent filesystem type reported after disabling journalling

Tags: ext4, parted, ext2

In trying to understand why [kworker flush uses 99% I/O and hangs file write on machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620804/kworker-flush-99-i-o-hangs-file-write-on-machine), I've disabled journalling on the ext4 data partitions using:

`tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdg1`

After a reboot, automatic mounting of the partitions via `/etc/fstab` entries failed:

```
# mount /mnt/das.f
mount: /mnt/das.f: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdf1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Odd.

Amongst our machines, the older were formatted as ext3 (long ago) and the newer ones have ext4. Because of this mixture, the common admin scripts use `parted` to automatically create `/etc/fstab` based on the actual partition types present.

However, after removing the journal on the ext4 partitions, `parted` reports it as ext2. Other tools still report it as ext4.

Which is correct?  Does removing the journal "transform" the filesystem from ext4 to ext2, or is this a bug in `parted` and `file`?

```
# parted /dev/sdc1 p
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sdc1: 7580GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  7580GB  7580GB  ext2

# file -sL /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=8fde102f-1047-4b3b-83f9-43c40face046 (extents) (large files)

# blkid /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: UUID="8fde102f-1047-4b3b-83f9-43c40face046" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8935788a-939d-4d2c-8495-dc38afc47164"
```

(The volume mounts ok if `/etc/fstab` is manually changed to ext4...)

Machine: Centos 8.1, 4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code there is a difference in how libparted and libblkid detect ext version. The version is not written in superblock and both tools use supported features to distinguish between versions.

For ext3 without journal both tools will report ext2 which makes sense because the difference between those two is basically only the journal support.

For ext4 libblkid checks for ext4 specific features like large file or file type support and if these are present it will report the device as ext4. Libparted does similar checks but only if the journal is present so it will report every ext filesystem without journal as ext2. I'd say this is a bug but I guess it depends.

Libblkid ext superblock scanning code is available [here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/libblkid/src/superblocks/ext.c) notice that `probe_ext3` checks for journal support but `probe_ext4` does not.

Libparted ext code is available [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parted.git/tree/libparted/fs/ext2/interface.c) and in `_ext2_generic_probe` it checks for ext4 only when ext3 check passes so it will never try to detect ext4 on devices without journal.